# Wordpress 500 internal error after loading backup sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Working with wordpress and my client used to go through someone else for their site. When they parted ways they were given a buddypress backup, an sql backup, and the entire wordpress install in file format. What I did ways load up a default wordpress install then add the theme/child theme they were using. Everything worked fine until I added the sql backups in phpmyadmin. The layout of the site broke, wasn't receiving any css, and when I logged in (using the pass and usr in the database) It gave me a 500 internal server error.

So my question is what do I need to change in order to get this to work? Or perhaps theres a better way of going about loading their backups that I'm overlooking as I don't work with wordpress often.

Comment: what does the internal server error say?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. But you should look at the server's error logs to get details about the 500.

Comment: In the wp_options table you likely need to update the 'siteurl' and 'home' fields if you haven't done so already. Could also be an .htaccess issue. Kind of hard to guess at 500 error causes without more info.